# Matrix Algebra Help

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can someone please explain to me how for $Z$, $V \epsilon S^n$, $t \epsilon R$
$$(Z+tV) = Z^{1/2}(I + tZ^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2})Z^{1/2}$$

I think I'm missing some fundamental aspect of matrix algebra. I've been using the [matrix cookbook](http://www.mit.edu/~wingated/stuff_i_use/matrix_cookbook.pdf) for help

edit: I removed the first part because in typing it out for the question, I realized my mistake!

Comment: Just distribute the first $Z^{1/2}$, then the second $Z^{1/2}$. There's nothing complicated going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First multiply the $Z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ on the left through the parentheses.
$$
Z^\frac{1}{2}(I+tZ^{-\frac{1}{2}}VZ^\frac{1}{2})Z^\frac{1}{2}=(Z^{\frac{1}{2}}+tZ^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}VZ^{-\frac{1}{2}})Z^{\frac{1}{2}}=(Z^{\frac{1}{2}}+tVZ^{-\frac{1}{2}})Z^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$
Remember that $Z^0=I$. Now multiply the $Z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ on the right through the parentheses.
$$
Z^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}+tVZ^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}=Z+tV
$$